# How do I downgrade ddev to an older version?

Tags: ddev

I have ddev 1.21.3.

I would like to downgrade to 1.21.1.

I tried `brew install ddev@1.21.1` but it couldn't find it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see the faq, https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/basics/faq/#how-can-i-install-a-specific-version-of-ddev

You brew unlink ddev and use the install script. Unfortunately brew no longer has good ways to use versions other than current.